# disable a direct access to a specific web page in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Is there a trusted way to disable the direct access to an special web page? I mean I want to open it only by clicking on a Button for example. I know I can access to the webpage by using this code but It can not prevent accessing to the web page directly (Pasting the url or typing it):

```
 Response.Redirect("~/Code.aspx")
```

Thanks

Comment: The web is stateless by nature. So one way you could get around this is set a flag when the user clicks the button (store the flag in Session) and then check for that flag in the Page_Load of Code.aspx. If the flag isn't there, redirect them to a different page. If the flag is there, remove it and continue loading.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot because I don't have the time to test this now (I can see some downvotes coming already!), but...

In the "Code.aspx" page, check for Session["allowed"]. If the value is not there, end the response.

Next, make another page (from where Code.aspx can be accessed). In this page, set Session["allowed"] and then do a Server.Transfer() to Code.aspx, which will then run OK.

Finally, at the end of processing Code.aspx., remember to clear the Session["allowed"] variable again.

Hope this makes even vague sense :)

Comment: I know this but there are some pages between these two pages and if a user open the first page, then the session will be saved and he could access the secound page easily.

Comment: Kill the session variable after you check for it :) - set it to null or nothing (C# and VB.NET respectively)

Comment: I used this method but the pages between my pages are some APi webpages from other webpages. I mean if a person click on the first page it will be saved and then He will be directed to the API webpage and know He can easily open the secound page, Because the session is stored and it is not still directed to the secound page.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to write a piece of code on page load that checks the contents of `HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")` - if it's blank, a user has navigated to the page directly and you can handle it that way.

Comment: This can be circumvented from the client side

Answer (score 0):

On the source page create a token into a hiddenfield. To your button add PostBackUrl property and let it point to your destination page.

On the destination page you can validate that the request was made from your allowed source page. And you dont need to use session and all its drawback.

Check this [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for detailed information about how to use the mentioned property.