# How block the direct access to a webpage in web.config?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-config

Is there a way to block the direct access to an specified webpage(Pasting or typing the url) in the ASP.NET web.config file? Thanks

Comment: Could you give us a better use case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [disable a direct access to a specific web page in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24247893/disable-a-direct-access-to-a-specific-web-page-in-asp-net)

Comment: I want to prevent the user to paste or type the url in the browser bar and then access to it. But it should be accessible by GEt, POST or response.redirect("...") methods.

Comment: Use url rewrite if you dont wan the user to access the page with full path. or '<deny users="?" />' in web config for specify location

Comment: Thanks chinz.But may you help me more? I am new to it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Request.UrlReferrer object.  That gets information about the URL of the client's previous Page request that linked to the current URL.

```
if(Request.UrlReferrer != null)
{
    string PreviousPage = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
}
```

If client not come from the any page then Request.UrlReferrer is null.